# loop bus waiting time with randomly stopping

Tags: probability

> A bus runs on a loop. It takes to the bus 10min to complete the loop. You go to the bus station at random times. Along the way the bus driver randomly stops for 10 min with a $p$ chance (only one time each loop). What is the expected waiting time?

I saw series of answers. I just want to confirm my understanding.

The bus will stop randomly in a loop (station to station). Suppose bus stopped at $x$ min from station. When you arrived station,

1. if bus is after the stopping place (>x), the probability of stopping is 0;
2. if bus is before the stopping place (<x), the probability of stopping is $p.$

Therefore, bus will stop with probability $x/10*p.$ So the expected waiting time is
$$5 + \int^{10}_010*(\dfrac{x}{10}*p)\dfrac{1}{10}dx=5+5p.$$
Am I right?

Comment: does sitting on the bus in the station count as waiting

Comment: I doubt $5+p/2$ is correct.  If $p=0$ (the bus never stops) then you would get $5$ as you have.  But if $p=1$ (the bus always stops) then you would get $10$ rather than $5.5$.  Why do you have $(\dfrac{x}{10}*p)\dfrac{1}{10}$?

Comment: @Henry sorry I forget to multiplying 10,  the answer should be $5+5p.$ And pls see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simpler without having to worry about the distribution of the stopping place (it's true even when the stopping place isn't uniform).

If the bus doesn't stop, the expected time is $5$ (expectation of uniform distribution). It doesn't matter whether or not the speed of the bus is constant.

If the bus does stop along the way, the expected time is $10$. Again, expectation of a uniform distribution. As before, it doesn't matter whether the speed of the bus is constant (in particular, that it is $0$ for $10$ minutes straight).

So the total expectation is $$E(\text{wait time} \mid \text{no stop}) P(\text{no stop}) + E(\text{wait time} \mid \text{stop}) P(\text{stop}) = 5 \cdot (1-p) + 10 \cdot p \,.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you're refering to wait time before the bus leaves the station, the average time to complete a journey is $10p + 10$ minutes. On average the bus is half way through its journey so you can expect to wait $5p + 5$ minutes before the bus leaves from the station.

If you are referring to time spent waiting to get on the bus, the probability that the bus is already at the station is $p/2$ and the average wait time when the bus isn't at the station is 5 minutes.

$\frac{p}{2}\cdot0+\left(1-\frac{p}{2}\right)\cdot5=5-\frac{5p}{2}$

Comment: I think $5p+5$ is what I mean. But how to understand average adding (stopping) time is $10p/2$ directly rather than using conditional probability?